# Trying to create a Text Line class for c-strings

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ and I'm having a bit of trouble implementing my first program. I need to create a Line class which simply contains an array of `char` (c-string) as well as a length and a max capacity. The `linePtr` member variable is of type `char*`. Here is what I have:

Line.h:

```
#pragma once

#ifndef LINE_H
#define LINE_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Line {

private:
    char* linePtr{nullptr};
    int lineLength;
    int lineCapacity;

public:
    Line(); //default ctor
    Line(char);
    ~Line();

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const Line& l);

};

#endif // !LINE_H
```

Line.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "Line.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::strcpy;
using std::strlen;

const int LINE_CAPACITY = 5000; //arbitrarily set

Line::Line() {
    cout << "Default ctor" << endl;

    linePtr = new char[1]{ '\0' };
    lineCapacity = LINE_CAPACITY;
    lineLength = 0;
}

Line::Line(char cstr) {
    cout << "ctor Line(char cstr)" << endl;

    linePtr = new char[2];
    lineCapacity = LINE_CAPACITY;
    lineLength = 1;

    linePtr[0] = cstr;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Line& l) {
    return out << l.linePtr;
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Line.h"

using namespace::std;

int main() {

    Line l1;
    cout << l1 << endl;

    Line l2('x');
    cout << l2 << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

When I run with debugging, when the `linePtr` field it is written I get the message: "Error reading characters of string". I'm sure I'm doing something stupid but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Do you have a `Line.h` to show us?

Comment: An answer already gives the solution.  But by the way,  I think that LineCapacity should hold the number of bytes allocated.  Otherwise it's useless.

Comment: Why not use `std::string` and save yourself from all the headaches?  With using `char*`, try to copy `Line` objects, and you will see that you're still in trouble.

Comment: The purpose of the assignment is to simulate the string class with c-strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not null-terminating the character array in the second constructor. Add this line at the end of the method:

```
linePtr[1] = '\0';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, tried that but I still get the same error. Even my default constructor is giving me the same error. Debugger showing that even the values for lineLength and lineCapacity are ridiculous (-858993460)

Comment: @KarlSamaha: -858993460 is 0xCCCCCCCC in hex. Visual Studio's CRT implementation uses this value in a debug build to indicate uninitialized data. Do you see those values even after the c'tor ran to completion?

Comment: Also if the compiler is optimizing your code you might see strange values for variables in the debugger. Turn off optimization with /Od when debugging.

Comment: Ah I see, no the length values are working correctly after the ctor finishes, but the linePtr is still giving me a hex number, which I'm assuming is a memory address

Comment: Oh it's working now! Thanks :D! I thought the null character automatically gets inserted at the end of the array and I did not have to worry about it

Comment: Very little happens automatically for you in C and C++, especially with strings ;-)